# Constructor issue for descended class

Tags: c#

I feel like an entire dork. I've been a coder for a while, and I haven't run into this in a language before, I guess, I've always been overriding the constructor with "additional" things.. so, I'm truncating some classes for explanation:

```
public enum Flags : ushort
{
   Item = 1,
   Player = 2
}

public class Item
{
    private Flags _flags;
    private int _owner;
    private String _pwd;

    public Item(Flags flags, int owner, String pwd = null)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        _flags = flags;
        _pwd = pwd;
    }
}

public class Connection
{
    ... stuff irrelevant to question
}
```

So, when a player logs in, I want to be able to take a descendant of `Item` which has type `Player`, and has a connection - as realistically it is just an item.

So I did this as a starter:

```
public class Player : Item
{
    public Connection Conn;
}
```

It said:

> Item does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Well, In my eyes, I never said it did.. Player will never be "created" only copied from item, an existing item, I'm adding to it, one extra property (not that this is what will stay as my code, but it was a starting point) .. So, I don't want to have to manually copy the actual 20+ properties from one to the other. Realistically I want to be able to use

```
Player p = (Player)item_wanted;
```

and then assign it a connection.. `p Player` is never going to be created directly. I don't want to have connection assigned to Item, as it's only active players, and technically a player could have more than one connection.

Of course, the first stupid thought is a constructor of

```
Public Payer(Item i)
{
    this = (Player) i;
}
```

Yeah sadly can't do that, can we? :( but in effect, that's almost what I want!

Before you ask, I did consider adding Item to connection... But logically you wouldn't think of it that way round...

So, how do I get round it? I want to add one property and call it something else...

OK, I get why it said about the instructor, disappointed it didn't go with the available ones in the original class, but fine, I get that. However, as the originating item is already alive, I don't want copies. I wanted to add functionality... I give in. This question can be closed.**

Comment: A class with no defined constructor is implicity given a default constructor. When you inherit it is assumed that the implicit default constructor will call the default constructor on the base class but, your base class does not have one.

Comment: I think it might also be design issue. Why your `Player` needs to inherit an `Item`? Does it model 'is' relation (ie. `Player` is `Item`)?

Comment: If you have ever played a mud/muck this will make more sense. The player is an item in a database only difference is it gets logged in as and has the Player flag. So, once connected, I wanted easier access at the moment, my connection has an item attached to it, but, the reality is the player has a connection.. You want to say "Player.NotifyLine" not find connection of player and tell connection to send the line.  Items only exist once. As a result, duping all properties to Player, would mean you then need to constantly be updating the underlying item..  realistically Item as viewed as Player

Comment: Of course it would mean some code duplication, but it seems really to be better design approach. And the underlying item might will be updated when you call your Player properties setters, seems fair to me. Oh and btw, if you say 'question may be closed' - you're the one that can close it:)

Comment: Isnt it funny how I wrote this nearly 3 years back and today 2 people down vote it

Answer (score 3):

The first problem: Item has private properties, therefore descendants will have no access to _flags. If you declare them to be protected, descendats will have access, but you will not be able to use a constructor like this:

```
    public Player(Item i) : base(i._flags,i._owner,i._pwd)
```

So, if you make Item properties public, this will work:

```
public enum Flags : ushort

{
   Item = 1,
   Player = 2
}

public class Item
{
    public Flags _flags;
    public int _owner;
    public String _pwd;


public Item(Flags flags, int owner, String pwd = null)
 {
  _owner=owner;
  _flags=flags;
  _pwd=pwd;
 }
}

public class Connection
{
    public Connection()
    {
    }
}
public class Player : Item
{
    public Connection Conn;
    public Player(Item i) : base(i._flags,i._owner,i._pwd)
    {
        // and add your "additional thing"
        // This calls the base constructor, and then you can add codes...
    }

}
```

So, you can do this:

```
    Item p = new Item(Flags.Item,12);  // Item is something existing
    Player x = new Player(p);
```

Note, that Player x and Item p are not the same. Player x is created from Item p, so modifying p. will no effect x..
So code:

```
    Item p = new Item(Flags.Item,12);
    Player x = new Player(p);         // instead of: Player p = (Player)item_wanted;
    p._owner = 20;
```

would display 20 (as p._owner), and 12 (as x._owner). After creating a new Player based on an Item, you can "forget" the Item.

Comment: Thanks.. close, but still not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your child class constructor **implicitly** calls the default constructor of your parent class. In your parent class you haven't defined any constructor with 0 parameters that is why you are getting this error.

Although you haven't defined any constructor for your `Player` class. It will assume a default constructor like the following call.

```
Player() : base()
{
}
```

To resolve this issue you may create an empty default constructor in your base class `Item` or call your specific constructor with keyword `base` in your child class with the constructor.

```
Public Payer(Item i) :base(arg1,arg2,arg3)
{

}
```

[Using Constructors - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called
>   explicitly using the base keyword, then the default constructor, if
>   there is one, is called **implicitly**.

Comment: As I said though, technically Im not going to be ever doing a "new" player, only copying an Item to it, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @BugFinder, then define a private constructor in your player class, and define an empty constructor in your Item Class

Comment: It told me I cant use This = (Player)i because this is read only - I had tried that.

Comment: @BugFinder, I missed that earlier, you can't assign anything to `this`. It represents the current object and it is readonly.

Comment: So, is there an easy way to turn an Item to Player, when the reality is adding the Connection class? without doing all the copying property by property?

Comment: @BugFinder, one way to go is to have an Item type property in your player, and assign that the value from the constructor. Other than that I think there is a way to override the implicit casting operator, but I am not sure. I think its wrong from OOP point of view to convert a base class object to child class, it should be the other way. From Child to Parent. You may ask this as a new question, since this question was about problem with the constructor

Answer (score 2):

If you inherit from `Item` you need to call its constructor from `Player`:

```
public Player(Flags flags, int owner, String pwd = null) : base(flags, owner, pwd) 
{
   // Do something else
}
```

Or you have to define a constructor with no parameters on `Item`.

Comment: I havent needed to with other languages, and rather than reinvent the constructor I was happy with the one that was there.. is there no more elegant a way to do this?

Comment: I think there's no other way, maybe using reflection but would not be elegant for sure! :)

Comment: No, that wouldnt :( It seems such a simple thing to want do, seems bizarre that its so tough to manage

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to Item of:

```
public Item() { };
```

Comment: I dont want to run foul of then potentially creating an item with no settings.. A Player will always be an Item + connection, even if the connection isnt set, or lost I wanted to identify them as a pair.. I will never be creating an empty player, it will always be set to a current item. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `Player` to copy properties from `Item`, then inheritance might not be the way to go. You could use composition:

```
class Player
{
    Item item;
    public Player(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item; // store reference to item here, it will point to the same object you used for construction, no copying needed later
    }
}
```

You also don't have to expose `item` as public property to call `player.Item.Flags` etc, you may just create wrapper properties for you `Player` class:

```
class Player
{
    Item item;
    public Player(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item; // store reference to item here, it will point to the same object you used for construction, no copying needed later
    }

     public string Name { get { return item.Name; } } // etc...
}
```

Comment: As I said, the Player will always be a whole item, Is there no way to do the (Player)item without a constructor and manually copying all settings, so in the event of updating item, i dont have to remember to update player?

Comment: Then composition might be way to go. Check updated answer.

Comment: I had thought of that, but, the reality is, I dont want to end up with code of Player.item.name etc, as its Player.Name, Player.flags.. its 100% identical to item, bar it has an active connection.. Nor do I want to store connectios on saving my items, so I dont want to add connection to item, as realistically in the long run 90% items wont be players.

Comment: Then you may create wrapper properties for that. You can even have some interface, let's say `IItemOwner`, and make your `Player` class implement it. I don't know the details of your design, but it might be really worth considering. Like I said in comment to question: does this particular inheritance model 'is' relationship? Can you say: `Player` is an `Item`? If not, then you may just misuse inheritance.

Comment: Player is always an item. an item is not always a player.

Comment: Then `Player` needs same arguments for constructor as `Item`, and pass them via `: base(...)` like many replies here are saying. There is no other way, because, if you only care about being able to assign Item to Player, it would mean Player does not have any additional logic/data compared to Item.

Comment: Then Im clearly barking up the wrong tree. Item "i" already exists, irrelevant of if they are logged in or not. Once logged in, I wanted to add functionality to them as they are a player.. 

I will give up on it

Comment: So, `Item` is some player info, whereas `Player` is player that's in the game. Doesn't seem to me like you could say: 'Player is an item`, and use inheritance to model it.

Comment: All DB items are of type "Item" Player only is differentiated by the player flag, and then it can do things like "talk". I wanted to make this easier but it cant be done the way that makes sense to read

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A
{
   private int _p;
   public A(int param) { _p = param;}
}

public class B : A 
{
    public B(int param) : base(param)
    {
    }

    public int x { get; set; }
}
```

If you have an instance of A (`var item = new A(1);`) you can't convert it to B.
But if you have an instance of B (`var player = new B(1);`) - you can cast it to A:

```
var casted = (A)item;
```

So, what do you mean by *Player will never be "created" only copied from item, an existing item*?